# Math operators in Java for Matrix multiplication

Tags: java

Hi I am fairly new to Java coding so please excuse for any silly errors or questions. I got this code from some internet source which multiplies two matrices and gives the resultant one in Java. I have edited it for my own use. The code is as follow:

```
 for ( c = 0 ; c < 3 ; c++ )
         {
            for ( d = 0 ; d < 1 ; d++ )
            {   
               for ( int k = 0 ; k < 3 ; k++ )
               {
                  Math.sum = sum + transformation[c][k]*sub[k][d];
               }

               multiply[c][d] = sum;
               sum = 0;
            }
         }

         System.out.println("Product of entered matrices:-");

         for ( c = 0 ; c < 3 ; c++ )
         {
            for ( d = 0 ; d < 1 ; d++ )
               System.out.print(multiply[c][d]+"\t");

            System.out.print("\n");
         }
```

So now im getting red lines under sum and multiply saying 'sum cannot be resolved or is not a field' and 'multiply cannot be resolved to a variable'. Can anyone please explain the reason for the error and how it can be resolved. Thanks

Comment: Their is no Math.sum function/method in the math library http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: The redlines you're seeing in your IDE are compiler errors. The compiler is telling you quite correctly that it doesn't know what `sum` or `multiply` are, since you haven't declared or defined those variables. More broadly, learning Java from incomplete random examples you find online is not a good approach. Pickup a copy of the book HeadFirst Java instead.

Comment: what is number of rows and columns in Matrix A & B?

Comment: matrix A is 3x3 and matrix B is 3x1

Answer (score 1):

public class Multiply {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows=3, columns=3;
    double multiply[][] = new double[rows][columns]; // product of transformation X sub
    double matA[][] = { { 2, 3, 6 }, { 1, 4, 6 }, { 4, 1, 3 } },
       matB[][] =  { { 2, 1, 0 }, { 3, 5, 1 }, { 3, 2, 1 } }, 
       sum;

    for (int k = 0; k < columns; k++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < rows; c++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int d = 0; d < columns; d++) {
                sum = sum + matA[c][d] * matB[d][k];
            }
            multiply[c][k] = sum;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Product of Matrix A & B matrices:-");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            System.out.print(multiply[i][j] + "\t");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The data type of individual elements is not clear from the question, `multiply`, `matA`, `matB`, `sum` could all be `double`.

Comment: +1 Yes. Along with datatyeps, order of matrices is not given.

Comment: changed. This is just example, User needs to use accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
    int multiply[][] = new int[somesize][somesize] ;
    for ( c = 0 ; c < 3 ; c++ )
    {
           for ( d = 0 ; d < 1 ; d++ )
           {   int sum = 0; // Creating local variable 'sum'
                  for ( int k = 0 ; k < 3 ; k++ )
                  {
                        sum = sum + transformation[c][k]*sub[k][d];
                  }

                  multiply[c][d] = sum;

            }


     }
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at test.main(test.java:162)

Comment: getting this error for the line sum = sum + transformation[c][k]*sub[k][d];

Comment: @user3492146 : That means either `sub` or `transformation` does not have element at some position `1`. First see whether both of these arrays have size of `1x3`  or not. I think your array size is less than `1x3` thats why you got `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

I really is only that your taking the Math library sum method and setting it to a value; The method is supposed to return a value to you Sum = Math.sum(5,4)